# How to include a PHP.file using @media?

Tags: php, css

Is it possible to use include or something simular to include a PHP-file using $media?

... like

```
@media (min-width: 100px) and (max-width: 319) {
include'small_menue.php';
} 

@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 800) {
include'big_menue.php';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry i can't comment, but why do you want to do something like that.
media is a css element
you can directly use a php code like

```
<?php
include'small_menue.php';
?>

<?php
include'big_menue.php';
?>
```

if those files are what you need there then you can use the following code

```
@media (min-width: 100px) and (max-width: 319) {
<?php include'small_menue.php'; ?>
} 

@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 800) {
<?php include'big_menue.php'; ?>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment as well.

This does not echo anything when I try

```
<style  type="text/css">
@media (max-width: 320px) {
<? echo 'small'; ?>
} 

@media (min-width: 321px)  {
<? echo 'big'; ?>
} 
</style>
```